# Heat Equation - Similarity Solution

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, heat-equation

Let $ s = xt^{-1/2} $ and look for the solution to the heat equation $ u_{t} = u_{xx} $ which is of the form:  $ u(x,t) = t^{-\frac{1}{2}}f(s) $, which satisfies the condition $ \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} u(x,t) \; \mathrm{d}x = 1.$

This is what I've tried so far:

$ u = t^{-\frac{1}{2}}f(xt^{-\frac{1}{2}})$

$ u_{t} = -\frac{1}{2}t^{-\frac{3}{2}}f(xt^{-\frac{1}{2}}) +  t^{-\frac{1}{2}}f'(xt^{-\frac{1}{2}})(-\frac{1}{2}xt^{-\frac{3}{2}})$

$ u_{t} = -\frac{1}{2}t^{-\frac{3}{2}} \left[ (f(s) + sf'(s) \right]$

$ u_{x}  = t^{-\frac{1}{2}}f'(xt^{-\frac{1}{2}}) \cdot t^{-\frac{1}{2}}  $

$ u_{xx} =  t^{-\frac{1}{2}}f''(xt^{-\frac{1}{2}}) \cdot t^{-\frac{1}{2}} \cdot t^{-\frac{1}{2}} = t^{-\frac{3}{2}}f''(s)$

$ u_{t} = u_{xx}$

$ -\frac{1}{2}t^{-\frac{3}{2}} \left[ (f(s) + sf'(s) \right] = t^{-\frac{3}{2}}f''(s) $

$ f''(s) + \frac{s}{2}f'(s) + \frac{1}{2}f'(s)=0$

Basically, this is where I get stuck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$f^{′′}(s)+\frac{s}{2}f^′(s)+\frac{1}{2}f(s)=0$$
$$f^{''}(s)+{(\frac{s}{2} f(s))}^{'} = 0 $$
$$f^{'}(s)+\frac{s}{2}f(s) = A $$

$$ (f(s).\exp(\frac{s^2}{4}))^{'} = A\exp(\frac{s^2}{4}) $$
$$f(s).\exp(\frac{s^2}{4}) = f(0)+\int_{u=0}^s A\exp(\frac{u^2}{4}) \:du$$

you can integrate at any point you want , i chose the 0 but you can choose another one

Comment: Thank you so much!  I can't believe I didn't see that!

Comment: good answer. mehran baba, if you in this situation you can also set $v = f'$ and what you get is a first order ode in $v$ for which is possible to separate variables! :D